# Extract numbers in a String using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have the following sample of strings below:

```
rotate(0deg)
rotate(12.5deg)
rotate(360deg)
rotate(15.09deg)
```

I just want to extract the  numbers:

```
0
12.5
360
15.09
```

The part of the string which is static are the following:

Beginning:

```
rotate(
```

Ending:

```
deg)
```

How will I do that in javascript?

Comment: [`str.match(/(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/)[1]`](https://regex101.com/r/jS7fG1/1)

Comment: `str.split(/\D+/).filter(isFinite)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/\brotate\((\d+(?:.\d+)?)(?=deg\))/g
```

and use capture group #1 for your number.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yF5pW2/2)

**Code:**

```
var re = /\brotate\((\d+(?:.\d+)?)(?=deg\))/g; 
var m;
var matches=[];

while ((m = re.exec(input)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex)
        re.lastIndex++;
    matches.push(m[1]);
}

console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Number()` , `.replace()` with `RegExp` `/.*\(|deg\)$/g`

```js
var arr = ["rotate(0deg)",
  "rotate(12.5deg)",
  "rotate(360deg)",
  "rotate(15.09deg)"
];

var res = arr.map(function(n) {
  return Number(n.replace(/.*\(|deg\)$/g, ""))
});

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this regex : `(\d*\.?\d+)`